# How to make a sync DDB query in node.js lambda function?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I am trying to query DDB in a node.js lambda function. I refer to this document:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.NodeJs.04.html

The codes look like this:

```
docClient.query(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Unable to query. Error:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    } else {
        console.log("Query succeeded.");
        data.Items.forEach(function(item) {
            console.log(" -", item.year + ": " + item.title
            + " ... " + item.info.genres
            + " ... " + item.info.actors[0]);
        });
    }
});
```

The problem is this is an async call depending on call back. While I would like to wait until the query is finished, so that I can use the query result before my function ends. But I cannot find a sync DDB query API for node.js. How can I resolve the problem?

Comment: So AWS now support Node 8.X, you can use async/await, I've upvoted your answer because some not very nice person downvoted you ignoring the fact you're new to stack!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely will not find a NodeJS sync DB function. Node is intended to work asynchronously, especially in the case of access to outside systems (like your database).

The processing of your script will continue when the callback has fired. Check for error or use the resulting data.

Comment: Looking back to when I was first learning Node, every time I *thought* I needed something to 
be synchronous, it was because I was doing it wrong. +1

Comment: I think you are right. Though I still don't find a solution for my problem now, I agree that I have to think about how to solve it in asynchronous way or by callback.

Comment: The trick is either to: 1) Put the code that uses the DB results *into the callback*. or 2) Use the `async/await` version of the DB library call to `await` the results of the query, which will "look synchronous" within the same block.